# Temporarily hide objects included in models added with sceneBuilder

Tags: autodesk-forge

I would like to temporarily hide objects in a model that I have added using the SceneBuilder Extension.
However, I do not see any change on the screen even though the result of changeMaterial is true as shown below.

Do I need to do any additional operations?

Thanks for your help.

```
           const customModel = await (
              sceneBuilderExt
            ).addNewModel({
              conserveMemory: false,
              modelNameOverride: 'Custom Object Model',
            });

    const exstingMaterial = this.customModel.findMaterial(id);
    const newMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      ...exstingMaterial,
      visible: false
    });
    const res = this.customModel.changeMaterial(exstingMaterial, newMaterial);
    this.customModel.sceneUpdated();
    this.viewer.impl.invalidate(true, true, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing materials is not necessary. We can just call [viewer#hide( dbIds, model )](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/GuiViewer3D/#hide-node-model) to hide objects in the models added with sceneBuilder like viewer native objects.

```js
viewer.hide( dbIdOfTheObjectInCustomModel, this.customModel.model );
```

To get selected objects' dbIds in the custom model scenes added by SceneBuilder, we can simply call [viewer#getAggregateSelection](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/GuiViewer3D/#getaggregateselection-callback), then the code snippet will become:

```js
let selSet = viewer.getAggregateSelection();

//Suppose we only select objects in one custom scene.

viewer.hide( selSet[0].selection, selSet[0].model );
```